# Cyclomatic complexity - draw control flow graph for this java statement

Tags: testing, metrics, control-flow-graph

Can anyone help with this?

```
while (x > level)
    x = x – 1;
x = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclomatic complexity can be computed using the formula provided [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/cyclomatic_complexity.htm).

```
Cyclomatic complexity = E - N + P 
where,
  E = number of edges in the flow graph.
  N = number of nodes in the flow graph.
  P = number of nodes that have exit points
```

For your case, the graph should look like this:

```
---------------                ----------
|  x > level  |----- NO ------>| x = x-1|
|-------------|                ----|-----
       |      |---------------------
       |
      Yes
       |
-------|----------
| End while (if) |
-------|----------
       |
       |
   ---------
   |  x = 0 |
   ----------
```

(not an ASCII art person)

So, the `cyclomatic complexity` should be:

```
E = 4, N = 4, P = 2 => Complexity = 4 - 4 + 2 = 2
```

**[edit]** 
`Ira Baxter` points out very well how to simplify this computation for languages like `Java`, `C#`, `C++` etc. However, identifying the conditionals must be carefully performed, as shown [here](http://www.leepoint.net/principles_and_practices/complexity/complexity-java-method.html):

```
- Start with a count of one for the method.
- Add one for each of the following flow-related elements that are found in the method.
    Returns - Each return that isn't the last statement of a method.
    Selection - if, else, case, default.
    Loops - for, while, do-while, break, and continue.
    Operators - &&, ||, ?, and :
    Exceptions - catch, finally, throw, or throws clause.
```

Comment: And for structured languages like Java, you can compute it as #conditionals plus 1. (1+1 ==> 2 for this example).

Comment: Considering breaks and continue are always accompanied by a conditional (otherwise the loop immediately exits), wouldn't you only count the conditionals?

Comment: @nonconvergent - I guess `if` + `break` count as one, not two. If I rewrite the while in the OP like: `while(true) .. if (x >= level) break`, according to the rules I would obtain +2 (`if` and `break`). My feeling is both `if .. break` and the dummy `while` should be exceptions, since the complexity seems the same. Anyway, I am not really sure and that's a good questions for Programmers.SE.

Comment: `if (condition) { return; }` would also be a candidate for counting as one not two, I think.